# Using .dockerignore file with sbt-native-packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

The Dockerplugin for sbt-native-packager works well for my play2.5 app, but it seems that is sends too much to the docker daemon (about 49mb) when I run `docker:publishLocal`.

I've tried to put a `.dockerignore` file in the root directory of the project, but it doesn't seem to be used.

Where do I have to put the `.dockerignore` file or is there a setting for sbt I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to add a mapping for the file to get copied into your packaged directory:

```scala
mappings.in(Universal) +=
  ((baseDirectory.value / ".dockerignore"), ".dockerignore")
```

Comment: According to http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#configuration there is no mapping support